# Simulink Transfer Functions

Tags: simulink, transfer

How can you determine what function is being plotted below in the time domain?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for a more complex answer than "look at the scope".

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking how to get the inverse Laplace form of this transfer function. Try using the [ilaplace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ilaplace.html) function. Maybe you can create a [MATLAB function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) that does this.